# How to use JSON to make an Array local then parse it into a page

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, if-statement, local-storage

I need to use Local Storage for a class and I'm using JSON's stringify function to do this. I am trying to parse it out but it isn't working for some reason. When I use my if statement the ct2 and cn2 arn't actually working. here is the html first.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Graphic Design</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="classList">
        <div id="classes" data-role="listview"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
            <h4>Department of Art</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

And here is the JSON javascript file named "json.js"

```
var cn = ["Art 150 Drawing 1", "Art 170 Basic Design 1", "Art 171 Basic Design 2", "Art 274 Typography 1", "Art 282 Computer Art 1", "Art 235 Ancient/Medevil Art", "Art 236 Renaissance/Mid-19th Century", "Art 237 Impressionism/Post Modernism", "Art 324 History of Photography", "Art 225 Photo 1 or Art 226 Digital Photo", "Art 351 Illustration 1", "Art 374 History of Graphic Design", "Art 370 Layout & Design 1", "Art 371 Layout & Design 2", "Art 372 Design & Production 1", "Art 451 Illustration 2", "Art 470 Advertising Graphic Design", "Art 471 Corporate Graphic Design", "Art 472 Typography 2", "Art 490 Internship", "Art 495 Portfolio Class"]
var ct = ["n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"]

localStorage.setItem("classTaken", JSON.stringify(ct));
localStorage.setItem("className", JSON.stringify(cn));
```

---

Here is my code that "retrievesData" and attempts to output the parsed info into the "#classList" div in listview format.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("json.js", function (data) {

        var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("className");
        var cn2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);

        var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("classTaken");
        var ct2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);



    for (var i = 0; i < ct.length; i++) {
        var info = '<li>' + cn2[i] + '</li>'


        if (ct2[i] == "y") {
            $('#classes').append(info);
        } else {
            $('#notTaken').append(info);
        }
    }
});
    });
```

Comment: can you reduce your title into a more descriptive question?  You risk a "too localize" close vote on this.

Comment: Please define "isn't working". What is it actually doing, and how is that different than what you expect?

Comment: sorry, isn't working as in the page has nothing on it when I go to it. I got it to work without the json function but when I try to stringify it and then pull it from local stograge and parse it, I don't get any information on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's never too late. I found this old problem I was working on in college and decided to finish it. This was a proof of concept for keeping track of which classes you'd taken within your major. I was attempting to store data in an array. Convert it to JSON and hold it in local storage. Then, convert that JSON back to an array and sort the data accordingly based on my if statement.

So being very green I went about this a completely bizarre and creative way.

My first bit of javascript was me attempting to create the json. My second bit of code was me trying to parse that json back into an array and sort the data.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/righteous_coder/pen/BPyyJd) of a functional version of what I had originally set out to do.

**My HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Graphic Design</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content" id="classList">
  <h2>Classes Taken</h2>
    <div id="classes" data-role="listview"></div>
  <h2>Classes Not Taken</h2>
    <div id="notTaken" data-role="listview"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
        <h4>Department of Art | Class Course List | Graphic Design</h4>
  <script>
    getMyDataPlease();
  </script>
</div>
```

**My JavaScript**

```
var className = ["Art 150 Drawing 1", "Art 170 Basic Design 1", "Art 171 Basic Design 2", "Art 274 Typography 1", "Art 282 Computer Art 1", "Art 235 Ancient/Medevil Art", "Art 236 Renaissance/Mid-19th Century", "Art 237 Impressionism/Post Modernism", "Art 324 History of Photography", "Art 225 Photo 1 or Art 226 Digital Photo", "Art 351 Illustration 1", "Art 374 History of Graphic Design", "Art 370 Layout & Design 1", "Art 371 Layout & Design 2", "Art 372 Design & Production 1", "Art 451 Illustration 2", "Art 470 Advertising Graphic Design", "Art 471 Corporate Graphic Design", "Art 472 Typography 2", "Art 490 Internship", "Art 495 Portfolio Class"]

var classStatus = ["y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y"]

function convertToJSONPlease() {
// convert both arrays to JSON objects and store them in local storage
localStorage.setItem('className', JSON.stringify(className));
localStorage.setItem('classStatus', JSON.stringify(classStatus));
}

// calling function
convertToJSONPlease();

function getMyDataPlease() {

// get your data from local storage and parse it 
var classes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('className'));
var classState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('classStatus'));

// loop through the class state
for (var i = 0; i < classState.length; i++) {
    var info = "<li>" + classes[i] + "</li>";

    // if the class state is set to yes, add the class to the taken list, otherwise add it to the not taken list
    if (classState[i] == "y") {
    $('#classes').append(info);
    } else {
    $('#notTaken').append(info);
    }
}
};

// calling function
getMyDataPlease();
```

There are so many errors with my original code that it won't be worth going through. The important thing to note was the steps:

1. Create your data
2. Convert your data to JSON
3. Store your JSON in local storage
4. Pull your JSON from local storage
5. Parse that JSON into two arrays
6. Loop through one of the arrays while using the classState variable to sort the className variable into "Class Taken" or "Class
   Not Taken"
7. Append that class names respectively.

One thing to note about my CodePen, I put everything in one file and called it accordingly but the point is that you could take this prototype and create a class tracking app that uses local storage to remember which classes the user has taken.

Answer (score -2):

Use `cn = {key:'value',key2:'value2',...}` for declaring JSON, in your example you are declaring arrays.

Comment: is it not possible to stringify my arrays the way they are? The idea was to have cn be the information organized by the ct being "y" or "n" without creating a key for every class name.

Comment: That's not JSON either, that's a Javascript object literal. Also, JSON does support arrays: http://json.org/

Comment: Well js object literals are JSON. And you can declare arrays and functions in place where I wrote 'value'. Anyways, why not making a class names a keys for your ct array?

Comment: Javascript Object literals aren't JSON. They are Javascript Object literals. JSON is always a string.

Comment: You are right, json is subset of js object literals, they are not same. But my answer still works.

Comment: No, there is no such thing as an object literal that is also JSON. They are mutually exclusive. One is a string representation of the other. `var cn = '[1,2]'` for example is valid JSON, whereas `var cn = {key:'value'}` isn't JSON at all (even if it were a string the key and value would need to be enclosed in double quotes).

Comment: Ok, you are right, but name being JSON or literal won't help him solve the problem. I just said what worked for me many times in hope he would find solution.